# How to create a date based on year and month name in dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a date based on year and month name.I wrote a code to print dates in the console.

code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'month': ['APRIL', 'MAY', 'JUNE', 'JULY', 'AUGUST', 'SEPTEMBER', 'OCTOBER', 'NOVEMBER', 'DECEMBER', 'JANUARY', 'FEBRUARY', 'MARCH'],
    'kpi': ['SALES', 'SALES QUANTITY', 'SALES', 'SALES', 'SALES', 'SALES', 'SALES', 'SALES QUANTITY', 'SALES', 'SALES', 'SALES', 'SALES'],
    'financial_year': [2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023]
    }

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (pd.to_datetime(df['financial_year'].astype(str)  + df['month'], format='%Y%B'))
```

It generates output like below:

```
0    2022-04-01
1    2023-05-01
2    2023-06-01
3    2023-07-01
4    2023-08-01
5    2023-09-01
6    2023-10-01
7    2023-11-01
8    2023-12-01
9    2023-01-01
10   2023-02-01
11   2023-03-01
```

But I want to generate output in the below format:

```
0    2022-04-30
1    2023-05-01
2    2023-06-30
3    2023-07-31
4    2023-08-31
5    2023-09-30
6    2023-10-31
7    2023-11-01
8    2023-12-31
9    2023-01-31
10   2023-02-28 
11   2023-03-31
```

Required output is based on some conditions:

1. If the `kpi` is `sales` then the `day` in the `date` should be last day of that particular month otherwise it should be `01`.
2. For the month of April last day should be based on leap year.

I need the output when all the columns are of object type.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Is November correct? It should be `2023-11-01`

Comment: yes .you are correct.I will edit the output@jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter rows with `kpi` for `SALES` and add [`offsets.MonthEnd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html) for last day of month:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['financial_year'].astype(str)  + df['month'], format='%Y%B')

df.loc[df['kpi'].eq('SALES'), 'Date'] += pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) 
print (df)
        month             kpi  financial_year       Date
0       APRIL           SALES            2022 2022-04-30
1         MAY  SALES QUANTITY            2023 2023-05-01
2        JUNE           SALES            2023 2023-06-30
3        JULY           SALES            2023 2023-07-31
4      AUGUST           SALES            2023 2023-08-31
5   SEPTEMBER           SALES            2023 2023-09-30
6     OCTOBER           SALES            2023 2023-10-31
7    NOVEMBER  SALES QUANTITY            2023 2023-11-01
8    DECEMBER           SALES            2023 2023-12-31
9     JANUARY           SALES            2023 2023-01-31
10   FEBRUARY           SALES            2023 2023-02-28
11      MARCH           SALES            2023 2023-03-31
```